# How to make text number animated when display in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, jetpack-compose-animation

I want to show text with numbers and I wanted to achieve is to animate that text while displaying it. The animation is it should increase the counter from zero to the target value number. I tried using **animateIntAsState** but it's not working.

This is the state I tired :

```
 val daysCounter by animateIntAsState(
        targetValue = days ,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 5000,
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
```

And text :

```
        Text(
                text = "$daysCounter",
                fontSize = 40.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`animateIntAsState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#animateIntAsState(kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.Function1)):

> When the provided `targetValue` is changed, the animation will run automatically.

Your animation doesn't work because `targetValue` is static.

The first recomposition must be done with an initial value, and the next recomposition you can pass the target value. For example, you can use `LaunchedEffect` if you need to start the animation instantly(or with some delay) when the screen appears:

```
var days by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val daysCounter by animateIntAsState(
    targetValue = days,
    animationSpec = tween(
        durationMillis = 5000,
        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
    )
)
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    days = 300
}
```

More info about animations in Compose can be found in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animate-as-state).

Comment: can we have a double value with decimals animate like this?

Comment: @HarishPadmanabh you can animate float for sure, there's `animateFloatAsState` - since float is used in all places in Compose, it should be enough. you can also check out other functions `animate*AsState`, including basic `animateValueAsState` which will allow you animating any type at all - you just need to provide a way to convert it to vector of values to animate through

Comment: How can we the digits to scroll up and down in animation