How to use correctly animateIntAsState?
I just want a simple one-time animation where the numbers 0-10 are displayed for 10 seconds.
I expected that for such a simple task it would be enough to use animateIntAsState, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I need it. This is immediately equal to the target value.
Tried this:
@Preview
@Composable
fun OneTimeAnim() {
    val curValue = animateIntAsState(
        targetValue = 10,
        animationSpec = tween(10000, 0, LinearEasing),
        label = ""
    )

    Text(text = "${curValue.value}")
}

Аfter that I tried to apply LaunchedEffect as advised in other topics:
@Preview
@Composable
fun OneTimeAnim() {
    var target by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val curValue = animateIntAsState(
        targetValue = target,
        animationSpec = tween(10000, 0, LinearEasing),
        label = ""
    )

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        target = 10
    }

    Text(text = "${curValue.value}")
}

I can't even get the animation effect from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71000500/17623714.
What surprises me is that rememberInfiniteTransition and its animateValue are easy to use, because you don't need to use LaunchedEffect, SideEffect and etc, but for one-time animation there are such difficulties.
Please, tell how to use correctly animateIntAsState?

Your second example works fine for me. Since LaunchedEffect doesn't run in a preview: Are you sure you tested it on an (emulated) device?

Yes you are right. All this time I was running it only in Preview mode Android Studio. Thanks a lot)

As Leviathan said, LaunchedEffect doesn't work in a preview mode. All this time I was running it only in Preview mode Android Studio(
Looked at the insides of the function animateIntAsState and I understood why an additional remember-variable is needed.
LaunchedEffect(channel) {
        for (target in channel) {
            // This additional poll is needed because when the channel suspends on receive and
            // two values are produced before consumers' dispatcher resumes, only the first value
            // will be received.
            // It may not be an issue elsewhere, but in animation we want to avoid being one
            // frame late.
            val newTarget = channel.tryReceive().getOrNull() ?: target
            launch {
                if (newTarget != animatable.targetValue) {
                    animatable.animateTo(newTarget, animSpec)
                    listener?.invoke(animatable.value)
                }
            }
        }
    }

The line animatable.animateTo(newTarget, animSpec) will be executed after assigning a new value to the remember-variable target from LaunchedEffect.
Should I delete this post or leave it for others in the same situation?

Leave it here is my opinion.
